# Check if value is not empty and not null in angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I check if value is not empty and not null.

in Controller:
`$scope.data.variable = 'some valid data';`

`<div ng-if="data.variable != ''">something else</div>`

Thanks

Comment: <div ng-if="data.variable !== '' && data.variable !== null">something else</div>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

since both null and empty are falsy values

div.variable if `not` `null` or `empty` will evaluate to `true` and if either of `null` or `empty` will evaluate to false

```
 <div ng-if="data.variable">something else</div>
```

Comment: If configure strict mode templates in Angular, this might throw an error.

Comment: The value could be a valid false boolean value. This is not the same as null or empty

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you have such a function is your controller:

```
$scope.isEmpty = function(value){
return (value == "" || value == null);
};
```

And your HTML:

```
<div ng-if="!isEmpty(data.variable)">something else</div>
```

If this function will be useful in many of your pages I suggest you put it on the $rootScope, so that it's recognized in the entire application.

Comment: your solution is more readable and conveys the developer's intentions right away.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like in your case, I think you're expecting either an empty string, or `null`. To write a reasonable check, I would consider it best to go about it like this;

```
$scope.isValid = function(val) {
    var ret = true;
    if (angular.isString(val)) {
        ret = ret && (val.length > 0);
    }
    return ret && (val !== null);
}
```