# Angularjs don't display "null" in for each loop

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs application I have a `<select>` field. Like so:

```
<select name="deliveryAddress"
   class="selectpicker"
   ng-options="address as a.Address1 + ' ' + a.HouseNumber for a in customer.deliveryAddress track by a.Id"
   ng-model="customer.deliveryAddress.selected">
</select>
```

In most cases `a.Address1` is the streetname like "Miles St" and HouseNumber is the house number like "51". But in some cases, `a.Address1` is "Miles St 51" (it includes the house number field). Than the select box shows: "Miles St 51 null", because `a.HouseNumber` is null. Is there a way to prevent displaying "null" within the selectbox, or am I forced to make two separate `<select>` fields?

[image: Image of the address field where the null text is visable.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value is not empty and not null in angular template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634736/check-if-value-is-not-empty-and-not-null-in-angular-template)

Comment: can you try this one ?

ng-options="address as a.Address1 + ' ' + (a.HouseNumber ? a.HouseNumber : ' ') for a in customer.deliveryAddress track by a.Id"

Comment: It does not @flakerimi , knowing that the variable is null or empty doesn't matter, I need a solution for both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there u go    ng-options="address as a.Address1 + ' ' + (a.HouseNumber ? a.HouseNumber : ' ') for a in customer.deliveryAddress track by a.Id"